# Sorted list to file

Tags: python

I wrote a code:

```
str = "aaa
       aaa
       aaa
       abb
       abb
       ccc"
str = '\n'.join(sorted(set(str.split())))
print(str)
```

Prints Output as:

```
aaa
abb
ccc
```

But when I try to store str into a file using:

```
    text_file = codecs.open(filename, "w", "utf-8")
    text_file.write(str)
    text_file.close()
```

File is stored as:

```
aaaabbccc
```

I want to store it as

```
aaa
abb
ccc
```

Did I go wrong at any place?

Comment: That's a bit strange.. Are you sure the `\n` character is there?

Comment: you can use `text_file.write_lines(unjoined_sequence)`. you might be on a platform that doesn't support '\n' as new lines (might need '\r\n')

Comment: When I see console output, it displays in new line. But when I use push it to file it shows everything as a single line. Need help.. I'm on windows. It displays good with other programs.

Comment: Why not just print to file before doing the join, then join after to do whatever you need to do?

Comment: @raser: in which case they'd be translated for you.

Comment: I'd not use `codecs.open()`; it has plenty of problems. Use plain `open()` unless you have Unicode, in which case go for `io.open()`.

Comment: It is just windows(notepad) problem. Open the file with [`notepad++`](http://notepad-plus-plus.org)and you will see the newline. Or better, read back the file with python and check that the newline is there.

Comment: Thanks.. :) It's just problem with Notepad